# Getting the Error Circular dependecy between the following tasks :BaseGameUtils:generateReleaseRFile

Tags: javascript, java, performance, android-studio, build.gradle

i try to Generate signed bundle but it give me this error
Circular dependecy between the following tasks Circular dependency between the following tasks: :BaseGameUtils:generateReleaseRFile --- :BaseGameUtils:generateReleaseRFile (*)  (*) - details omitted (listed previously)

[image: image1]

here the file build.gradle(Module:BaseGameUtils)

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

how can i fix this error ?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @Omar looks like out of the 4 api dependencies you have some issue. Please check this out https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/issues/82